# Setting X-Axis format dynamically for temporal type variable

Tags: vega-lite

I am using bar chart in my dashboard and x-axis is time axis and user has input to select the axis like Day, Month and Year. Based on user input, corresponding  format should get applied to X-axis

I am using below setting
"labelExpr": "format(datum.label,data('source_0')[0]['xaxisDisplayFormatType'])",

In xaxisDisplayFormatType if i passed "%" or"$", it is getting applied correctly, the same i have tried "%m %Y" or "Y" it is not working

[Vega configuration](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAAyUAIxKUGggAEzpBQX86Vn8AMzpACpZAByo1ajpma3pAFrBCACeAGZs6siY+QCkAJogAL4KifkAQqkZlJW5+UUlZaXldY3NrZTtXUq9A0MBY5NTALozIMjqANb51urBcLJQbMo0smRooAAHgCQH0aHBBMp8iglJgejg4PlZGwEL8osEkICaBAQYIkJ5BPo-hYMlM7j0QWCIVD0HlYfDEehMIgcIN0UpMdjcfiIQBRQE4N7oM7DAAU-kwDAQlDxBIUEqQooA5DIGOooHAAPrpJUASji6WucSVp0GwyV1110zJUyAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- `format` does numeric formatting (like fixed width floats or scientific notation). The function for temporal formatting is [`timeFormat`](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#timeFormat).
- The value of the label is `datum.value`, not `datum.label`.

So what you want is:

```json
"labelExpr": "timeFormat(datum.value, data('source_0')[0]['myformat'])"
```

[link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAAyUAIxKUGggAEzpBQX86Vn8AMzpACpZAByo1ajpma3pAFrBCACeAGZs6siY+QCkAJogAL4KifkAQqkZlJW5+UUlZaXldY3NrZTtXUq9A0MBY5NTALozIMjqANb51urBcLJQbMo0smRooAAHgCQH0aHBBMp8iglJgejg4PlZGwEL8osEkICaBAQYIkJ5BPo-hYMlM7j0QWCIVD0HlYfDEehMIgcIN0UpMdjcfiIQBRQE4N5M0xwABig2GAAp-JgGAhKJFonAFDKkJKAOQyBjqKBwAD66XVAEo4ulrnF1acJQF1dcjdMyVMgA)